# How to get a tight output when using pst-tree package and standalone class?

Tags: pstricks, standalone, preview, pst-tree

```
\documentclass[preview,border=3pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-tree}

\psset{levelsep=2,treesep=-2,angleA=90,angleB=-90,arm=12pt}

\def\psedge#1#2{\ncangle{#2}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\psTree{\Tcircle{36}}
    \Tcircle{2}
    \psTree{\Tcircle{18}}
        \Tcircle{2}
        \psTree{\Tcircle{9}}
            \Tcircle{3}
            \Tcircle{3}
        \endpsTree
    \endpsTree
\endpsTree

\end{document}
```

The code produces a trimmed output as follows.

[image]

How to fix this issue so I can get a correct tight output?

### Edit:

For comparison purposes, let's comment some code in the preamble as follows.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt,preview,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-tree}

%\psset{levelsep=2,treesep=-2,angleA=90,angleB=-90,arm=12pt}
%
%\def\psedge#1#2{\ncangle{#2}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\psTree{\Tcircle{36}}
    \Tcircle{2}
    \psTree{\Tcircle{18}}
        \Tcircle{2}
        \psTree{\Tcircle{9}}
            \Tcircle{3}
            \Tcircle{3}
        \endpsTree
    \endpsTree
\endpsTree

\end{document}
```

The output looks fine!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
treesep=-2
```

use

```
treesep=2,
treeflip
```

which mirrors the orientation and calculates the bounding box correct.

### Code

```
\documentclass[preview,border=3pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
\psset{levelsep=2,treesep=2,treeflip,angleA=90,angleB=-90,arm=12pt}
\def\psedge#1#2{\ncangle{#2}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\psTree{\Tcircle{36}}
    \Tcircle{2}
    \psTree{\Tcircle{18}}
        \Tcircle{2}
        \psTree{\Tcircle{9}}
            \Tcircle{3}
            \Tcircle{3}
        \endpsTree
    \endpsTree
\endpsTree

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]